# Token management algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, operating-system

I have pool of tokens(Numbers 1-N). A process can take a token do its work. While process has the token no other process can take that token. But after some time the validity of a token expires after which it becomes free. For example we have token 1-10. Process A took token 1, process B took token 2. After some time validity of token 2 expired. After some time there will be holes in the token array with only some token as free and inorder to search for a available token I have to search full array. Which data structure/algorithm to use to optimally solve the problem

Comment: Is N constant or dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

linked list. Initialize the list with one node per number. remove the head from the list when you need to allocate a token. add it back to the list when the token expires. Tokens in the list will progressively go out of order, but that doesn't matter to your problem (I assume you don't need to get the smallest token available)

Comment: Ah! Thanks..Well if i want it to be sorted too. Will priority heaps be optimal ?